# How to parse following json string in angular 4

Tags: json, angular

[image]

```
{
    "-LAYrx3MjaZyn86aOHEa": {
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/e-godaam.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%20(1).png?"
    },
    "-LAYs4ELD5klKCliwP9v": {
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/e-godaam.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%20(2).png?"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? How do you want to parse it, and for what purpose?

Comment: The json contains the url of files stored in firebase cloud

Comment: Then use `json["-LAYrx3MjaZyn86aOHEa"].url` or `json["-LAYs4ELD5klKCliwP9v"].url` to access the url string? Is this what you're asking?

Comment: ["-LAYrx3MjaZyn86aOHEa"] is the randomly generated id by firebase and i don't know how to access it

Comment: If your problem is simply to get the urls from randomly generated id strings, I've posted an answer to fix that below. You might want to edit your question to reflect that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from your comment that the problem is that you do not know how to access the urls from the randomly-generated id strings.

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate over the keys of the object. I.e.:

```
var keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);
for(var key of keys) {
    // do something with jsonObject[key].url
    console.log(jsonObject[key].url);
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Comment: @Dhawal No problem! But I think you might want to edit your post to make the question more clear for posterity.